# How to use two different models in CreateView in django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have following models:

```
class BankAccount(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

class MoneyTransfer(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(BankAccount)
```

and url:

```
url(r'^accounts/(?P<pk>\w+)/send_transfer$', SendTransfer.as_view(), name='SendTransfer')
```

that means "I want to send money from Account with id=pk"

This is my view:

```
class SendTransfer(View):
    form_class = SendTransferForm
    template_name = 'dashboard/send_transfer.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = BankAccount.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        if instance.is_legal():
            if instance.organization.owners.all().filter(user__id=self.request.user.id).count() == 0:
                return None
        else:
            if instance.citizen.user.id != self.request.user.id:
                return None
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, self.get_context_data())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        sender = BankAccount.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])

        form = self.form_class(sender, self.request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            MoneyTransfer.objects.create(sender=sender,
                                     receiver=BankAccount.objects.get(id=self.request.POST['receiver']),
                                     total=float(self.request.POST['total']),
                                     when=timezone.localtime(timezone.now()),
                                     comment=self.request.POST['comment'])
            return redirect('AccountDetail', kwargs['pk'])

        data = self.get_context_data()
        data['form'] = form
        return render(request, self.template_name, data)

    def get_context_data(self):
        account = BankAccount.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return {'form': SendTransferForm(account, self.request.user),
            'user': self.request.user,
            'account': account}
```

I think there's a lot of redudant code for CBV. What can I do for shorting it?

**UPD**

my current code:

```
class SendTransfer(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
model = BankAccount
form_class = SendTransferForm
template_name = 'dashboard/send_transfer.html'

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    return super(SendTransfer, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    obj = super(SendTransfer, self).get_object(queryset)

    if obj.is_legal():
        if not obj.organization.owners.filter(user=self.request.user).exists():
            raise Http404
    else:
        if obj.citizen.user != self.request.user:
             raise Http404

    return obj

def form_valid(self, form):
    data = form.cleaned_data
    MoneyTransfer.objects.create(sender=self.object,
                                 receiver=data['receiver'], # ModelChoiceField in the form
                                 total=data['total'], # FloatField in the form, etc.
                                 when=timezone.localtime(timezone.now()),
                                 comment=data['comment'])
    return redirect('AccountDetail', self.object.pk)
```

last line of dispatch() method raises TypeError: **init**() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Could you post the full traceback? Either here, or on gist/dpaste.

Comment: http://dpaste.com/1FN36R6

Comment: I'm sorry. Last problem is beacause of three arguments of __init__ of my form. I've added get_form_kwargs and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CBVs are designed for code reuse. If you don't yet have another class that could benefit of code you posted, the actual amount of code is almost identical, be that a CBVs or a plain function.

But the more pythonic and Django-ish (from my biased POV) way would be to:

1. Inherit your class from the `FormView` instead of the `View`. That eases the form management a bit.
2. Add a `SingleObjectMixin` to get the object from url kwargs for free.
3. Move your object validation to the `get_object()` method. It's a good practive to raise 404 if your object doesn't validate.
4. Refactor out the `get_context_data()` as you already have all that data in your context (`request`, `form` and `object`)
5. Instead of relying on the `self.request.POST`, clean your data through the form.

   ```
   class SendTransfer(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
       model = BankAccount
       form_class = SendTransferForm
       template_name = 'dashboard/send_transfer.html'

       def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           self.object = self.get_object()
           return super(SendTransfer).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

       def get_object(self, queryset=None):
           obj = super(SendTransfer, self).get_object(queryset)

           if obj.is_legal():
               if not obj.organization.owners.filter(user=self.request.user).exists():
                   raise Http404
           else:
               if obj.citizen.user != self.request.user:
                    raise Http404

           return obj

       def form_valid(self, form):
           data = form.cleaned_data
           MoneyTransfer.objects.create(sender=self.object,
                                        receiver=data['receiver'], # ModelChoiceField in the form
                                        total=data['total'], # FloatField in the form, etc.
                                        when=timezone.localtime(timezone.now()),
                                        comment=data['comment'])
           return redirect('AccountDetail', self.object.pk)
   ```

Some of your code has gone thanks to the CBV magic, some just has moved to another methods. Take a look, I'd welcome your comments.

Comment: AttributeError: 'SendTransfer' object has no attribute 'object'

Comment: Not working yet. Debugger shows that get_object() is not calling

Comment: Right. I was pretty sure `SingleObjectMixin` handles that. Take a look, I've modified the code a bit.

Comment: I've added "self" as second argument to super()... at last line of dispatch and now this line raises TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)